# getting a number using regular expressions

Tags: javascript, jquery, regex

I have the following string:

PR-1333|testtt

I want to get the number 1333 using regular expressions in javascript. How can I do that?

Answer (score 0):

This will look for numbers in your text.

```
var text = "PR-1333|testtt";

var number = text.match(/\d+/g); // this returns an array of all that it found.

console.log(number[0]); // 1333
```